# Prepend a number with $ in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script ( using nouislider )

I wish to prepend the rangeThing values with $ sign as we are outputting prices.

Code I have is:

```
$("#slider").noUiSlider({
range: [0, 1000000]
,start: [350000, 700000]
,handles: 2
,step: 50000
,slide: function(){
  var values = $(this).val();
  $("span.rangeThing").text(
     values[0] +
     " - " +
     values[1]
  );
 }
 ,serialization: {
  to: [$("#exTO"),$("#exFR")]
  ,resolution: 1
 }
 });
```

The javascript creates a span like `<span class="rangeThing"></span>`

The output format is like this 200000 - 350000

I would like to format with ( commas ) as thousand separators, but thats gonna get messy. So I am trying to prepend the 2 sets of values with $ sign to signify a price.

So resultant output is like $200000 - $350000

I tried changing the values to something like this, but that didnt work lol.

```
$("span.rangeThing").text(
     + "$" + values[0] +
     " - " +
     + "$" + values[1]
  );
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track, and that the fact I am trying to echo $ could be the culprit, and perhaps I should use unicode, either way it isnt working.

Help appreciated

Comment: Why don't you put the $ in the HTML instead, just before the `<span>`?

Comment: The span is generated dynamically so makes sense to do it within the js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in one line to see what's going on:

- You are starting with a `+`
- The third line has double `+`

One line would be easier to read:

```
$("span.rangeThing").text("$" + values[0] + " - $" + values[1]);
```

Comment: Perfect thankyou, staring at something for long enough for some people brings the answer. For me it brings me to Stackoverflow. Thankfully. Awesome :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the unary plus in Javascript implcitly converts the operand to a number. This means that

```
 + "$"
```

actually evaluates to `NaN`.

Just place the `+` operator only between terms and things should go as you expect.

Comment: Exactly the issue I was facing, I thought I was on the right track, I had just nipped into a ditch lol. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, here's how you can add the commas if you want...

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
 x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}
```

To use it, just add the function to your file, and use it like this...

```
$("span.rangeThing").text("$" + addCommas(values[0]) + " - " + "$" + addCommas(values[1]));
```

Comment: I have seen similar code online, but not sure how to shoehorn that into my code. Thankyou tho, will keep playing

Comment: Oh NICE. That works perfect ( I did vote you up by the way ) Appreciate your code, looks much better now formatted. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your example there appears to be an extra `+` operator in the example you gave. As you see in the example you gave:

```
  $("span.rangeThing").text(
     values[0] +
     " - " +
     values[1]
  );
```

This will result in the string `"1 - 2"`, assuming values = [1, 2]. You should be able to simple add on the `$` by doing something like:

```
$("span.rangeThing").text(
     "$" + values[0] +
     " - " +
     "$" + values[1]
  );
```

As you've probably realized, the example you posted has some syntactic errors -- you have `+`'s everywhere! One thing to be aware of -- if you are trying to combine strings in the same line as numeric operations, you will need additional parentheses. So, if you had:

```
var string = "foo"+2+3+"bar";
```

your `string` would be:

```
foo23bar
```

whereas if you had:

```
var string = "foo"+(2+3)+"bar";
```

your `string` would be:

```
foo5bar
```

Comment: Thankyou, not sure I had "+" everywhere, I had one in the wrong place. Appreciate your reply, tho.